# Looking for existing scala combinator parsers

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators, scala-compiler

Is there a repository with parser written using [scala combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators)?
I am considering using scala combinators and it is dependent on finding existing parsers for popular languages (python, c, java, cpp, scala, haskell).

Answer (score 2):

[Scala fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/), the fastest parser combinator libraries for scala, provides an example parser for [python](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/tree/master/pythonparse) and [scala](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/tree/master/scalaparse).

Comment: Tahnks for the answer, but I am asking specifically for scala parser combinators. I am concered with maintainability and not speed. Do you know if they have the same API?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've misunderstood your question, but I would recommend to use scala fastparse instead. The syntax is slightly different, but it is just so much faster. They made a benchmarks comparing scala-combinators, fastparse and several handwritten parsers ([see here](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#Performance)) and fastparse was ~175 times faster than scala-combinators. I've used this library for quite a while and there weren't much/any changes since fastparse already passed the 0.x.x phase and is now stable.